# Cannot use pip to download scipy for wheel

Tags: python, pip, scipy, python-wheel

I need to install some Python packages in another computer that cannot connect to the Internet. I tried to use the `pip` command to access the packages I listed in `packages.txt` and put the wheel files in `./packs`. The full command is as follows,

```
pip3 download -d ./packs -r packages.txt -i https://mirrors.aliyun.com/pypi/simple/
```

However, `scipy` cannot be turned into the wheel format successfully. As a result, some packages (e.g., `scikit-learn`, `statsmodels`) that depend on `scipy` cannot be downloaded successfully as well. The full error message is shown below.

```
Downloading https://mirrors.aliyun.com/pypi/packages/84/a9/2bf119f3f9cff1f376f924e39cfae18dec92a1514784046d185731301281/scipy-1.10.1.tar.gz (42.4 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 42.4 MB 726 kB/s
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\liding\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' 'c:\users\liding\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\liding\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpcp63m4lc'
         cwd: C:\Users\liding\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-download-8bds6eo1\scipy_8794ca23ac8349ecb38e96bac61f61b7
    Complete output (21 lines):
    + meson setup --prefix=c:\users\liding\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32 C:\Users\liding\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-download-8bds6eo1\scipy_8794ca23ac8349ecb38e96bac61f61b7 C:\Users\liding\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-download-8bds6eo1\scipy_8794ca23ac8349ecb38e96bac61f61b7\.mesonpy-tq02oyez\build --native-file=C:\Users\liding\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-download-8bds6eo1\scipy_8794ca23ac8349ecb38e96bac61f61b7\.mesonpy-native-file.ini -Ddebug=false -Doptimization=2
    The Meson build system
    Version: 1.0.1
    Source dir: C:\Users\liding\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-download-8bds6eo1\scipy_8794ca23ac8349ecb38e96bac61f61b7
    Build dir: C:\Users\liding\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-download-8bds6eo1\scipy_8794ca23ac8349ecb38e96bac61f61b7\.mesonpy-tq02oyez\build
    Build type: native build
    Project name: SciPy
    Project version: 1.10.1
    WARNING: Failed to activate VS environment: Could not parse vswhere.exe output

    ..\..\meson.build:1:0: ERROR: Unknown compiler(s): [['icl'], ['cl'], ['cc'], ['gcc'], ['clang'], ['clang-cl'], ['pgcc']]
    The following exception(s) were encountered:
    Running `icl ""` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
    Running `cl /?` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
    Running `cc --version` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
    Running `gcc --version` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
    Running `clang --version` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
    Running `clang-cl /?` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
    Running `pgcc --version` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"

    A full log can be found at C:\Users\liding\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-download-8bds6eo1\scipy_8794ca23ac8349ecb38e96bac61f61b7\.mesonpy-tq02oyez\build\meson-logs\meson-log.txt
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\liding\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' 'c:\users\liding\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\liding\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpcp63m4lc' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Any ideas on how to resolve this issue? Thanks!

Comment: I think you should use `pip wheel` instead of `pip download`: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/repeatable-installs/#using-a-wheelhouse-aka-installation-bundles

Answer (score 0):

The most recent versions of scipy have no 32 bit wheels available. This is probably why pip is trying to build a wheel. You'd stand more chance if you were to use a 64 bit python.